# How to set mpg321 default audio devicetype

Tags: linux, command-line

I have been running mpg321 on a headless linux server, and its working well, however the devices audio out uses alsa which is not mpg321 default audio devicetype.
So when ever I want to play a mp3 I have to do something like:

```
mpg321 -o alsa /some/path/file.mp3
```

Is it possible to change mpg321 default devicetype to alsa so I do not have to keep using the -o option?

i.e would just be able to type

```
mpg321 /some/path/file.mp3
```

Comment: Not sure whether this is possible or not, but instead why not use a script that calls mpg321 with the `-o alsa` option and the file you pass to it?

Comment: @Karan because I have some software that uses mpg321 to run mp3 files, but I didnt not write the software and it would be much easier if I can change mpg321 default

Answer (score 0):

The man page says:

> mpg321 also allows configuring a default output device at **compile-time**, but run-time switching is always allowed

So if you want to change the default output device you have to do it at compile time. This is not so difficult. If you run a debian based distribution you can check that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains a line such

```
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
```

Create a `src` directory, go inside and do

```
apt-get source mpg123
```

Install needed development libraries such as `libasound2-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

Run the configure script and set the default output device

```
./configure --with-default-audio=alsa
```

You should see in the output log

```
Default output module ... alsa
```

The run make

```
make
```

and install the program

```
sudo make install
```

If you prefer you can also rebuild a debian package with the modified version of mpg321 in order to install it through `apt-get install`. To do so follow the instructions from the official debian wiki [Building Tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial).